# Why is my App component not rendering wrapped under Provider?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import createSagaMiddleware from "@redux-saga/core";
import { reducer } from "./Store/Reducer";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import sagas from "./Sagas";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

const sagaMiddleWare = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = configureStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleWare));
sagaMiddleWare.run(sagas);


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store = {store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);


reportWebVitals();
```

My  component is not rendering after adding the store and sagaMiddleWare.run to my code block.
But when I comment the configureStore and Sagamiddlware.run line, the app component renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`configureStore` works very differently from how you are using it. It is not a 1:1 drop-in replacement for `createStore` (in that case it would be pretty pointless to replace that).

It's very likely that you had an error message on the console that you just didn't notice.

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware.concat(sagaMiddleWare)
})
```

Note that you don't need to do `combineReducers` in another file like you probably did before, but can also do

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    sliceA: sliceReducerA,
    sliceB: sliceReducerB
  },
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware.concat(sagaMiddleWare)
})
```

Also, please be aware that the hint to use `configureStore` instead of `createStore` is not a hint a la "just replace this one thing" but a hint a la "you are writing an extreme outdated style of Redux there that is 4 times the code of modern Redux - please visit the official [Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) to learn how to use modern Redux".

Your old code will work, but you are making yourself a *ton* of unneccessary boilerplate & extra work by staying on the old style.

In the same way: generally we are nowadays recommending against using Redux saga for almost everything apart from the most complex use cases - things like data fetching are pretty much solved problems with modern Redux and you definitely don't need sagas for that. It's an oversized tool that is extremely hard to use with modern practices like TypeScript.